# What happens to a returned object when there's nothing to return it to?

Tags: python, return

This is just a fun thing that popped into my mind. Imagine a scenario, when you have

```
def returner():
    return 6
```

And then you call it:

```
six = returner()
```

Now 6 has been returned to `six`. But what happens to the 6 when you just call the function like the following?

```
returner()
```

Does the returned value just get discarded altogether? Or is it assigned to some hidden variable?

Comment: It gets discarded.

Comment: @Kasramvd that only happens in a Python interactive interpreter session.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm curious, by "discarded" does that mean _immediately_ garbage collected and memory freed? Perhaps that's another question...

Comment: Well, there is no guarantee on *when* it gets garbage collected, and practically it depends on the Python implementation (e.g. CPython uses reference counting, but IronPython uses something else  for example). But pretty much, yeah, it immediately gets garbage collected, and even if it wasn't immediate you wouldn't be able to access it anyway because no references exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on the interactive interpreter it gets printed out, if running standalone it gets discarded.

Comment: Also, it is assigned to `_` when using the interactive interpreter.